# How to list Apache Webserver configuration snippets?

Tags: listings, lstdefinestyle

Is there a way to list with lstlistings apache configuration files?

An example snippet is:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Comment: What did you already try and whats wrong with the output?

Comment: I have used the lstlisting package, with C or XML as the language defined, but there is no coloring. The whole block is treated as one. I was just wondering if there is a know generic solution for configuration files that does some kind of visualization.